# I have 2 activities & want to save the records in its fields, also must edit and update the fields and save it finally to send it to web service

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-sqlite

**FIRSTPAGE.JAVA** Here there few edit text and to be saved temporarily

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.first_page);

    applno = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.rpfno);
    financerups = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.finance_rupees);
    tenure = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tenure);
    assetname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.asset);
    rowId = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etRowInfo);
    page1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pf1);
    page2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pf2);
    page3 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pf3);
    page4 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.pf4);        
    save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_saveandcontinue);
    exit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_exit);
    info = (Button) findViewById(R.id.info);
    submitserver = (Button) findViewById(R.id.submitserver);
    edit = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bEdit);
    update = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bUpdate);
    delete = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bDelete);

    delete.setOnClickListener(this);
    save.setOnClickListener(this);
    exit.setOnClickListener(this);
    info.setOnClickListener(this);
    submitserver.setOnClickListener(this);
    edit.setOnClickListener(this);
    update.setOnClickListener(this);

    page2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstPage.this, Reference.class));
        }
    });

    page1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstPage.this, ProfilePage1.class));
        }
    });

    page3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstPage.this, Asset.class));
        }
    });

    page4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        startActivity(new Intent(FirstPage.this, OfficeUse.class));
        }
    });     
}    

public void onClick(View arg0)
{
    switch (arg0.getId())
    {
    case R.id.btn_saveandcontinue:

        boolean didItWork = true;

        try{                
            String Applno = applno.getText().toString();
            String Financerups = financerups.getText().toString();
            String Tenure = tenure.getText().toString();
            String Assetname = assetname.getText().toString();

            WayDataBase entry = new WayDataBase(FirstPage.this);

            entry.open();
            entry.createEntry(Applno, Financerups, Tenure, Assetname);
            entry.close();

        } catch (Exception e){
            didItWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
            d.setTitle("Dang");
            TextView tv = new TextView(this);
            tv.setText(error);
            d.setContentView(tv);           
            d.show();               
        }finally
        {
            if(didItWork)
            {
                /*Dialog d = new Dialog(this);
                d.setTitle("Heck Yea!");
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("SUCCESS");
                d.setContentView(tv);
                d.show();*/
                startActivity(new Intent(FirstPage.this, OfficeUse.class));
            }
        }
        break;              
    case R.id.info:
        startActivity(new Intent (FirstPage.this, TableView.class));
        finish();
        break;

    case R.id.bEdit:
        String s = rowId.getText().toString();
        long l = Long.parseLong(s);
        WayDataBase wdb = new WayDataBase(this);
        wdb.open();
        String returnedappno = wdb.getAppno(l);
        String returnedfinancerups= wdb.getfinancerups(l);
        String returnedtenure = wdb.getTenure(l);
        String returnedasset = wdb.getAsset(l);
        wdb.close();            
        applno.setText(returnedappno);
        financerups.setText(returnedfinancerups);
        tenure.setText(returnedtenure);
        assetname.setText(returnedasset);           
        break;          
    case R.id.bUpdate:
        break;          
    case R.id.bDelete:
        break;          
}}}
```

**OFFICEUSE.JAVA** Here there is few mor edit text to be saved with repect to the above fields using update method and with its corresponding unique field must be used to retrieval

```
    page2.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(OfficeUse.this, Reference.class));
        }});

    page1.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(OfficeUse.this,ProfilePage1.class));
        }});


    page4.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(OfficeUse.this, OfficeUse.class));
        }});

    page3.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(OfficeUse.this, Asset.class));
        }});        

    exit.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(),FirstPage.class);
            intent.setFlags(intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            intent.putExtra("EXIT", true);
            startActivity(intent);
        }});}

public void onClick(View arg0){
    switch (arg0.getId()){
    case R.id.btn_saveandcontinue:
        boolean isItWork = true;
        try{            
        String Applcname = applcname.getText().toString();
        String Employee = employee.getText().toString();
        String Psnem = psnem.getText().toString();
        String Branch = branch.getText().toString();
        String Clientid = clientid.getText().toString();
        String Schmcode = schmcode.getText().toString();
        String Agreeno = agreeno.getText().toString();
        String Promoschm = promoschm.getText().toString();
        WayDataBase entry1 = new WayDataBase(OfficeUse.this);
        entry1.open();
        entry1.createEntry1(Applcname, Employee, Psnem, Branch, Clientid, Schmcode, Agreeno, Promoschm);
        entry1.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            isItWork = false;
            String error = e.toString();
            Dialog d1 = new Dialog(this);
            d1.setTitle("Office Dang");
            TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
            tv1.setText(error);
            d1.setContentView(tv1);
            d1.show();
        }finally{
            if(isItWork){
                Dialog d1 = new Dialog(this);
                d1.setTitle("Office too work");
                TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
                d1.setContentView(tv1);
                d1.show();
            }}          
        break;
    case R.id.info:
        startActivity(new Intent (OfficeUse.this, TableView.class));
        finish();
        break;
    }}}
```

**WAYDATABASE.JAVA**

```
private static class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        db.execSQL( "CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
                KEY_ROWID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, " +
                KEY_APPNO + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AMT + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_TENURE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_ASSETS + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_APPLCNAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_EMPLOYEE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PSNEM + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_BRANCH + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_CLIENTID + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_SCHMCODE + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_AGREENO + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
                KEY_PROMOSCHM + " TEXT NOT NULL);" );}

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        db.execSQL(" DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        onCreate(db);
    }   }

public WayDataBase(Context c){
    ourContext=c;
}   
public WayDataBase open() throws SQLException{
    ourHelper = new DBHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase(); 
    return this;    
}
public long createEntry(String applno, String financerups, String tenure,String assetname){
    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
    cv.put(KEY_APPNO, applno);
    cv.put(KEY_AMT, financerups);
    cv.put(KEY_TENURE, tenure);
    cv.put(KEY_ASSETS, assetname);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv);        
}

public long createEntry1(String applcname, String employee, String psnem,
        String branch, String clientid, String schmcode, String agreeno,
        String promoschm) {
    ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
    cv1.put(KEY_APPLCNAME,applcname);
    cv1.put(KEY_EMPLOYEE,employee);
    cv1.put(KEY_PSNEM,psnem);
    cv1.put(KEY_BRANCH,branch);
    cv1.put(KEY_CLIENTID,clientid);
    cv1.put(KEY_SCHMCODE,schmcode);
    cv1.put(KEY_AGREENO,agreeno);
    cv1.put(KEY_PROMOSCHM,promoschm);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, cv1);
}

public void close(){
    ourHelper.close();
}

public String getData() {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_APPNO, KEY_AMT,KEY_TENURE, KEY_ASSETS,KEY_APPLCNAME,KEY_EMPLOYEE,KEY_PSNEM,KEY_BRANCH,KEY_CLIENTID,KEY_SCHMCODE,KEY_AGREENO,KEY_PROMOSCHM };
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
    String result=" ";
    int iRow = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ROWID);
    int iAppno = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_APPNO);
    int iAmt = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AMT);
    int iTenure = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_TENURE);
    int iAssets = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_ASSETS);
    int iApplcname = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_APPLCNAME);
    int iEmployee = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_EMPLOYEE);
    int iPsnem = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PSNEM);
    int iBranch = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_BRANCH);
    int iClientId = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_CLIENTID);
    int iSchmode = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_SCHMCODE);
    int iAgreeno = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_AGREENO);
    int iPromoschm = c.getColumnIndex(KEY_PROMOSCHM);       
    for (c.moveToFirst(); !c.isAfterLast(); c.moveToNext())
    {
        result = result + c.getString(iRow) + " " + c.getString(iAppno) + " " + c.getString(iAmt) + " " + c.getString(iTenure) + c.getString(iAssets) + 
                c.getString(iApplcname) + " " + c.getString(iEmployee) + " " + c.getString(iPsnem) + " " + c.getString(iBranch) + c.getString(iClientId) +
                c.getString(iSchmode) + " " + c.getString(iAgreeno) + " " + c.getString(iPromoschm) + "\n";
    }
    return result;  }

public String getAppno(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_APPNO, KEY_AMT, KEY_TENURE, KEY_ASSETS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null, null);       
    if(c != null)   {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String appno = c.getString(1);
        return appno;
    }
    return null;}

public String getfinancerups(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_APPNO, KEY_AMT, KEY_TENURE, KEY_ASSETS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null)   {
        c.moveToFirst();
        String rups = c.getString(2);
        return rups;
    }
    return null;    }

public String getTenure(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_APPNO, KEY_AMT, KEY_TENURE, KEY_ASSETS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String tenur = c.getString(3);
        return tenur;
    }
    return null;
}

public String getAsset(long l) {
    String[] columns = new String[]{ KEY_ROWID, KEY_APPNO, KEY_AMT, KEY_TENURE, KEY_ASSETS};
    Cursor c = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, KEY_ROWID + "=" + l, null, null, null, null, null);

    if(c != null){
        c.moveToFirst();
        String aset = c.getString(4);
        return aset;
    }
    return null;
}}
```

Comment: use static variables..

Comment: @bakriOnFire any tutorial related to this